# Django 1.7.1 makemigrations does not recognize an application

Tags: python, django, database-migration

I'm having the following Django apps structure:

```
projectname
    backend
        puzzle
            migrations
                ...
            models
                database.py
                ...
        user
            migrations
                ...
            models
                database.py
                ...
```

Both applications are registered in project settings file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'backend.puzzle',
    'backend.user',
 )
```

puzzle.models.database.py contains a Django model:

```
from django.db import models


class Puzzle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

so does user.models.database.py:

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Trying to make initial migration on all applications ignores 'user' app:

```
> python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, puzzle, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying puzzle.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
```

trying to migrate the app explicitly:

```
> python manage.py makemigrations user
No changes detected in app 'user'
```

setting 'managed' user model class Meta option to True did not help either.

How do I have Django recognize user app migrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you forgot to import `database` in the `user/models/__init__.py`:

```
from user.models.database import *
```